# How to configure dnsmasq on Mint-18 with NetworkManager?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, dnsmasq

I am learning linux networking.  I am very confused by the config file locations.  What I read on the web doesn't match how my machine is set up.

I am using Mint 18.  I am using network-manager & dnsmasq.

On the [dnsmasq setup page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html), they mention that dnsmasq can be configured in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.  I do not have this file...

However there is a `/etc/dnsmasq.d/network-manager` and there is also `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/`

I think (alhtough I do not know), that `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` is where I should place my config file.  Is this to do with NetworkManager's `plugins`?

If so what is `/etc/dnsmasq.d`?  Should I put my config file here?

Answer (score 0):

So by running `ps ax | grep dnsmasq` I was able to see where the config file comes from and what configurations are use currently...

```
>ps ax | grep dnsmasq
 1273 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

As can be seen `--conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint, running `whereis dnsmasq` points to the `/etc/dnsmasq.d` in which there is a `README` file describing that config files can be added to this directory and how to change the default config directory:

```
# All files in this directory will be read by dnsmasq as 
# configuration files, except if their names end in 
# ".dpkg-dist",".dpkg-old" or ".dpkg-new"
#
# This can be changed by editing /etc/default/dnsmasq
```